# Launch Windows 8 app with WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to launch a Windows 8 native application throuh a wpf application? i.e. can I launch the native Camera app using a wpf app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how it's done in WPF but Windows 8 applications can register with custom protocols. For instance the Mail app is registered with the "mailto" protocol.

If you search under settings for "protocol" you can see which applications are registered with which protocols. Sadly it doesn't look like the Camera app has any custom ones.